# How to install browser on Azure App Service deployment

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a need to use puppeteer sharp on a Azure app service deployment. Puppeteer sharp needs browser to do headless browsing. Does Azure app service comes with Edge installed? If not, How can I install a browser (chrome) in Azure app service deployment?

Answer (score 0):

You can't install Edge on App Service because it's a sandboxed environment.  The simplest solution is to use a virtual machine because you have more control.  You can also try to deploy your app in a container, install your dependencies and run it on App Service.

Answer (score 0):

A good way of getting around the no browser limitation of the app services is to use a 'browser as a service' service, like Browserless.

I've used Browserless for several months now and I've been very pleased with the service. They offer both usage-based and dedicated plans, to suit your needs and connecting to the service is very easy, like this example.

```
var connectOptions = new ConnectOptions() { BrowserWSEndpoint = "wss://chrome.browserless.io?token=YOURTOKENHERE" };
browser = await Puppeteer.ConnectAsync(connectOptions);
```

Once you've got your browser context, you can code your automated functionality as your normally would.